# How to add data from user form to a formatted table on a worksheet

Tags: excel, range, userform, vba

I have created a user form with text box as well as combo boxes. I cannot figure out how to add data to the formatted table on a worksheet using that user form. Please help!

The table looks like this:

```
Date  Inv  Company  Amount  Recd.Date  Recd.Amt.
```

I have enabled the total row option so I need the code to add a row in that particular table (after last entry and before total row) and automatically enter the data in that particular row.

Comment: Have you tried any thing?

Answer (score 1):

In its simplest form, you can just refer to range/cell objects on the worksheet, and set them equal to the object values on your userform.

Assuming you have some form objects like `TextBox1` and `ListBox1` (or, modify as needed)

`Range("A1").Value = UserForm.TextBox1.Value`

`Range("B2").Value = UserForm.ListBox1.Value`

You could do this through the form objects' event controls (e.g., `TextBox1_Change()` etc.) or you could add a button and use that buttons `_Click()` event to cycle through the form controls and write the data to the sheet where needed.